# How do I get the value from <input type=date> inside a cell in jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, datatables

I have a dynamically created (when I click on the cell) `<input type=date>` inside a cell of a DataTable.

I can select the date and looks good, now I get all the data in the table iterating each row because I process the data for every row, that works fine too, the problem is when I want to get the value from those inputs.

I tried with `data()` and `node()` but the value isn't shown on the HTML which I found out that was the way it's supposed to be, so I can't get it from the HTML, so I tried with the following code and it says it's undefined.

```
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        // Tried this - return undefined

        var node = this.node();     
        alert(node.cells[0].value);// The typeof(node.cells[0]) is object HTMLTableCellElement


        // also this - here shows the HTML without the updated date
        var data = this.data();     
        alert(data);

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not the TD that has the value, it's the input, use `node.cells[0]  .children[0]  .value`

Answer (score 5):

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below to access value of `input` inside the cell in the first column (`column: 0`).

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {       
    var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 0 }).node();

    console.log($('input', cell).val());
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/986capby/2/) for code and demonstration.